# Software to view a list of resources used by a site (images, videos, scripts, etc)

Tags: web-browser

A while ago I run into a program which allowed to see a list of all the resources used by a site (images, icons, videos, files, scripts, anything).

You could see the folder structure and upon clicking the /images directory for example you were able to see all the images for the page.

I also recall to stumble upon something similar on a browser that had the capability to "show resources" or something of the sort.

So it could be a program or a browser (+extension?).

I have the worst memory. I can't recall what it was so I wonder if anyone here actually knows.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mozilla Firefox can be used for that.

Browse to a web page, then go to **Tools - Page Info - Media**. It allows you to download media found on websites.

[image]

Comment: Another way to reach this: click on the icon to the left of the address bar, then click on "More information …" (or similar wording).

Answer (score 1):

Chrome can also be used for this, open the developer tools (Ctrl + Shift + "I") and go to resources.  If needed, tick the "preserve log" button and reload the page in order to make sure you get everything.

[image]